# Unable to get order id on bigcommerce store confirmation page

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am trying to get order id on confirmation page of big-commerce store after placing an order according to the following code:

```
fetch('/api/storefront/order/{{checkout.order.id}}', {credentials: 'include'})
.then(function(response) {
return response.json();
})
.then(function(myJson) {
console.log(myJson);
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

> {title: 'Not Found', type: 'about:blank', status: 404, detail: "Provided order Id doesn't represent a valid order"}

Answer (score 0):

That code looks correct to me. In what file have you placed the code? It should be in order-confirmation.html

Comment: I have added the code to the script manager via api. So the code runs automatically on the order confirmation page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if it will work in the Script Manager. In theory, it should. But try editing the order-confirmation.html file instead to see if that works.